# query in Oracle for incomplete parameters

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

how to fill in the request provided that the user has not entered all the numbers. I understand that through LIKE but how to implement ?

```
SELECT a.name, a.reg_number, a.inn
FROM aa a, cc b 
WHERE a.inn=:p_inn and (:p_inn LIKE '1%')
```

Comment: Not really clear what you need. Could you add some sample data and an example of input with expected result?  Btw, using numbers as table names is ... original.

Comment: tables are an example. I need that the user for example filled in parameter: p_inn not completely(instead of 123456 hammered only 1234) and at me that all remained were searched

Answer (score 0):

If the column needs to start with the parameters value?
Then you can use LIKE and concatinate % to the value.

```
SELECT a.name, a.reg_number, a.inn
FROM aa a
CROSS JOIN cc b 
WHERE a.inn LIKE :p_inn || '%'
```

Similar, if the value needs to be a part of it, then add the % to both sides.

```
WHERE a.inn LIKE '%' || :p_inn || '%'
```